# Mock Rest Server Response for Unit Testing

Tags: rest, unit-testing, mockrestserviceserver

In integration testing, I use a real remote server to consume REST APIs. 
What's the simplest way to provide those responses within a unit test w/o depending on external entity.

One possible approach is to build

```
public class TestHttpResponse implements   org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse

override

 @Override
    public StatusLine getStatusLine() {
      return new StatusLine() {
        @Override
        public ProtocolVersion getProtocolVersion() {
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getStatusCode() {
          return statusCode;
        }

        @Override
        public String getReasonPhrase() {
          return reasonPhrase;
        }
      };
    }
   ...
```

Is there a simpler and better way for mocking REST API response payloads?

Comment: have you tried to use apiary? https://apiary.io/ it has mocks option

Comment: looks like commercial. i wanted simple code which be hooked up in UT. Do you have example of using it in your UT?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of Mockito for this purpose:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#testing-with-mock-objects

The nice part about Mockito is how you can control it's behavior dynamically.